# Page becomes unresponsive

Tags: python, leaflet, javascript, openstreetmap, folium

I created a html file using leaflet to add markers to leaflet map using csv data. For parsing csv data I used papaparse. I did the same thing with python folium too and saved the output to a file called map.html. Both of them are unresponsive on opening on the browser and keep loading for ages. I thought it was because the dataset is huge and tried deleting some values and trying again

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>leaflet-map-csv</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>

  <style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="map"></div>

  <script>

  var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [24.2170111233401, 81.0791015625000], 
    zoom: 9,
    scrollWheelZoom: false,
    tap: false
  });


  var controlLayers = L.control.layers( null, null, {
    position: "topright",
    collapsed: false
  }).addTo(map);

  var light = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
  }).addTo(map);
  controlLayers.addBaseLayer(light, 'Carto Light basemap');

  var terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.'
  });
  controlLayers.addBaseLayer(terrain, 'Stamen Terrain basemap');

  $.get('lat-long.csv', function(csvString) {

    var data = Papa.parse(csvString, {header: true, dynamicTyping: true}).data;
    for (var i in data) {
      var row = data[i];

      var marker = L.marker([row.latitude, row.longitude], {
        opacity: 1
      })
      
      marker.addTo(map);
    }

  });

  map.attributionControl.setPrefix(
    'Leaflet Js openstreetmap'
  );

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my python code

```
import folium
from folium import plugins
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('lat-long.csv')
m = folium.Map([24.2170111233401, 81.0791015625000], zoom_start=5)

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row['latitude'], row['longitude']]).add_to(m)
m.save('marker.html')
```

Edit:
My csv file looks like this

```
,latitude,longitude
0,12.9943,80.231
1,0.0,0.0
2,12.994,80.23
3,12.994,80.23
4,1.0,2019040000.0
```

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger console? What do you se in browser debugger network section? An yes, having your data would help.

Comment: @TomazicM the page doesnt even load properly,much less let me inspect the source code and see if any bugs have been mentioned.

Comment: Properly loading or not, there must be some trace in the network section of the browser debugger.

Comment: An alternate approach could be to use QGIS and a plugin named Qgis2web.  After you load the CSV file into QGIS you simply use the plugin and it will export an HTML file and other relevant stuff.  No coding needed.

Comment: How many features are in your CSV file?

Comment: @TomazicM the page didnt load at all and it kept showing a popup wait or exit. I tried opening the inspect part but it didnt open

Comment: @GreyHippo Actually this is for the frontend part for a website. That's why I'm creating it from scratch instead of using QGis or even Excel. Also my original dataset has 44 columns and 104k rows. I stored the lat long values in a separate csv file for convinience

Comment: I doubt Leaflet (or any other mapping library for that matter) can handle display of 104K markers at once. I tried with 12K rows. It took 15 seconds for initial display of markers and another 15 seconds for markers shadow display. And then map was completely useless, every pan or zoom took ages to complete.

Comment: @SreelakshmiG Actually the Qgis plugin Qgis2web will create the "frontend" but with that many features it will be useless.

Comment: @GreyHippo is there a possibility that I can specify a range in leaflet map which will allow it to display markers for only that range?

Comment: Yes, you can use GeoJSON layer `.filter(feature)` option.

Comment: @SreelakshmiG you will need a wms or wfs server such as MapServer, Geoserver or QGIS server on the backend to handle loading of such amount of data. Since you have points you should go with wfs.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you are processing too much data.  Try to edit your CSV file to only include 100 points and see if that works.